# Azure AD - Insufficient privileges to perform requested operation by the application '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I work on a task that should invite users and add them in my azure active directory list. Before being able to access my app, the invited user should verify through email. This is the code I use:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(_config["AzureAd:ClientId"])
    .WithTenantId(_config["AzureAd:TenantId"])
    .WithClientSecret(_config["AzureAd:ClientSecret"])
    .Build();
ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var invitation = new Invitation
{
    InvitedUserEmailAddress = "mail@hotmail.com",
    InviteRedirectUrl = "https://url.com/",
    SendInvitationMessage = true

await graphClient.Invitations
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(invitation);
```

I found this snippet somewhere on the internet and judging by the comments, it seems to work. However, when I run my app and call this functionality, I get an error that says

> Code: Unauthorized Message: Insufficient privileges to perform requested operation by the application '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. ControllerName=MSGraphInviteAPI, ActionName=CreateInvite, URL absolute path=/...

In API permissions, I have a `User.Invite.All` permission under Microsoft Graph. Besides this I have `User.Read` as well but I don't think it's relevant for this at the moment. Has some of you stumbled upon an error like this and managed to successfully solve it? If so, would you be kind to share the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `client_credentials` flow. Which means it is not a User who is performing this task, but rather service credentials. You would need to provide `Application permissions`, rather than what you have set - `Delegated Permissions`.

If you don't see `Application Permissions`, its because you created an Azure AD B2C Application Registration. Rather, create the App Reg with the first option `Accounts in this organizational directory only (Contoso only - Single tenant)` .

These are the docs you need:

- [AAD Client Cred flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-%5Bdirectory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)
- [MS Graph API daemon app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)

This is correct method for AAD and AAD B2C tenant today.

Comment: Should I add these permissions under Microsoft Graph or under my web-api name?

Comment: Go to your Web Api App reg, go to permissions, assign MS Graph API as a permission with `Application permissions`.